# Create several dynamic Forms in my Controller, submit them all at once with one button

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I would like to create several Forms in my Controller. The first one only contains one field. I want to generate the other one according to a request (up to 50 fields).

When I do it, I get the following error : "This form should not contain extra fields."

I've been looking for a solution for two days and I'm starting to get a little desperate.
Thank you for your time.

This is the code I've written so far:
My Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\Etablissement;
use App\Entity\ReponseCompetenceEpreuvePratique;
use App\Repository\PracticalTestRepository;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type;

class PTestController extends AbstractController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    #[Route('/pTest', name: 'pTest')]
    public function index(PracticalTestRepository $practicalTestRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        $practicalTest = $practicalTestRepository->findOneByIdJoinedToMainObjective(1);

        $numberOfForms = 4;
        $formBuilders = [];

        if ($practicalTest === null) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        $objectiveNumber = 1;
        $numCompetence = 1;

        $mainObjectives = $practicalTest->getObjectifsPrincipaux();

        if ($mainObjectives === null) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        for ($i=1; $i <= $numberOfForms; $i++) {
            $formBuilders[$i] = $this->createFormBuilder();
        }

       $formBuilders[0] = $this->createFormBuilder()->add("lieu", EntityType::class, [
           'label' => "<u>Lieu</u> :",
           'label_html' => true,
           'required' => true,
           'class' => Etablissement::class,
           'expanded' => false,
           'multiple' => false,
           'invalid_message' => '',
           'attr' => [
               'class' => 'lieu'
           ]
       ]);

        for ($i=1; $i <= $numberOfForms; $i++) {
            foreach ($mainObjectives as $mainObjective) {
                $objectifDecret = $mainObjective->getObjectifOperationnelDecretEpreuvePratique();

                if ($objectifDecret === null) {
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
                }

                $objectifCompetences = $objectifDecret->getObjectifCompetences();

                if ($objectifCompetences === null) {
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
                }

                $competences = $objectifCompetences->getCompetences();

                foreach ($competences as $competence) {
                    $formBuilders[$i]
                    ->add('choice-' . $i . '-' . $numCompetence, EntityType::class, [
                        'label' => false,
                        'required' => true,
                        'choices' => $competence->getReponses(),
                        'class' => ReponseCompetenceEpreuvePratique::class,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'invalid_message' => '',
                    ]);
                    if($competence->getValeurAttendue()) {
                        $formBuilders[$i]
                            ->add("label-" . $i . '-' . $numCompetence, Type\TextType::class, [
                            'label' => false,
                            'required' => false,
                            'attr' => [
                                'class' => 'expectedValue'
                            ],
                            'invalid_message' => ''
                        ]);
                    }
                    $numCompetence++;
                }
                $objectiveNumber++;
            }
            $numCompetence = 1;
            $objectiveNumber = 1;
        }

        for ($i=0; $i <= $numberOfForms; $i++) {
            $formBuilders[$i] = $formBuilders[$i]->getForm();
        }
        $forms = [];
        foreach($formBuilders as $index => $builder) {
            $builder->handleRequest($request);
            $forms[$index] = $builder->createView();

            if($builder->isSubmitted()) {
                if($builder->isValid()) {
                    $this->addFlash("success", "Form $index est valide.");
                }
                else {
                    dd($builder);
                    $this->addFlash("error", "Test non valide.");
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('pTest/pTest.html.twig', [
            'forms' => $forms,
            'practicalTest' => $practicalTest
        ]);
    }
}
```

My 'pTest.html.twig' file :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Examen pratique{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/styles/practicalTest.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="{{ path('practicalTest') }}">
        <section class="relative mb-16 infos">
            <div class="pt-12 mx-auto text-center">
                <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">{{ practicalTest.title }}</h1>
                <h2 class="text-xl underline mb-10">Épreuve Pratique - Scénario nº{{ practicalTest.number }}</h2>
                {{ form_start(forms[0]) }}
                        {{ form_row(forms[0].lieu) }}
                {{ form_end(forms[0]) }}
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="quiz mx-auto">
                <ul
                    class="mb-5 flex list-none flex-row flex-wrap border-b-0 pl-0"
                    role="tablist"
                    data-te-nav-ref>
                    {% for i in 1..4 %}
                        <li role="presentation" class="tabs">
                            <a
                            href="#tabs-{{ i }}"
                            class="tab my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
                            data-te-toggle="pill"
                            data-te-target="#tabs-{{ i }}"
                            {% if i == 1 %}data-te-nav-active{% endif %}
                            role="tab"
                            aria-controls="tabs-{{ i }}"
                            aria-selected="false"
                            >Candidat {{ i }}</a
                            >
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                <!--Tabs content-->
                <div class="mb-6">
                    {% for i in 1..4 %}
                        {{ form_start(forms[i]) }}
                            <div
                                class="hidden {% if i == 1 %}opacity-100{% else %}opacity-0{% endif %} transition-opacity duration-150 ease-linear data-[te-tab-active]:block"
                                id="tabs-{{ i }}"
                                role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="tabs-{{ i }}-tab"
                                {% if i == 1 %}data-te-tab-active{% endif %}>
                                <table>
                                    <colgroup>
                                        <col class="col_code">
                                        <col class="col_main">
                                        <col class="col_ope">
                                        <col class="col_comps">
                                        <col class="col_nota">
                                    </colgroup>
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Objectif Principal</th>
                                        <th>Objectif Opérationnel Décret</th>
                                        <th>Objectif compétences</th>
                                        <th>Notation</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% set row = 1 %}
                                    {% set num_obj = 0 %}
                                    {% set num_comp = 0 %}
                                    {% set num_val = 0 %}
                                    {% set label_nota = '' %}
                                    {% set label_val = '' %}
                                    {% for objectifPrincipal in practicalTest.objectifsPrincipaux|sort((a,b) => a.number <=> b.number) %}
                                        {% set num_obj = num_obj + 1 %}
                                        {% for competence in objectifPrincipal.objectifOperationnelDecretEpreuvePratique.objectifCompetences.competences %}
                                            {% set row = row + 1 %}
                                            {% if competence.description %}
                                                {% set row = row + 1 %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if competence.valeurAttendue %}
                                                {% set row = row + 1 %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="col_border" rowspan="{{ row }}"><b>{{ objectifPrincipal.code }}</b></td>
                                            <td class="col_border" rowspan="{{ row }}"><b>{{ objectifPrincipal.titre }}</b></td>
                                            <td class="col_border" rowspan="{{ row }}">{{ objectifPrincipal.objectifOperationnelDecretEpreuvePratique.description }}</td>
                                            <td class="obj text-left">{{ objectifPrincipal.objectifOperationnelDecretEpreuvePratique.objectifCompetences.description }}</td>
                                            <td class="left_notation desc"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% set row = 1 %}
                                        {% for competence in objectifPrincipal.objectifOperationnelDecretEpreuvePratique.objectifCompetences.competences %}

                                            {% set num_comp = num_comp + 1 %}
                                            {% set label_comp = 'choice' ~ '-' ~ (i|trans) ~ '-' ~ (num_comp|trans) %}
                                            {% set label_nota = 'label-' ~ (num_comp|trans) %}

                                            {% if competence.valeurAttendue %}
                                                {% set label_val = label_nota ~ '-1' %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-left">&gt; {{ competence.titre }}</td>
                                                <td class="left_notation">{{ form_row(attribute(forms[i], label_comp), {'attr' : {'class' :'nota'}}) }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {% if competence.valeurAttendue %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text-left value">
                                                        <span class="mr-8">{{ competence.descriptionValeurAttendue }}</span>
                                                        {{ form_row(attribute(forms[i], label_nota)) }}
                                                        <span class="ml-6">{{ competence.uniteValeurAttendue }}</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="left_notation"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if competence.description %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text-left">{{ competence.description|nl2br }}</td>
                                                    <td class="left_notation"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        {{ form_end(forms[i]) }}
                        {% set num_comp = 0 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="validation">
                    <div class="group relative mt-4">
                        <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-gradient-blue opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-50 rounded-lg transition ease-out duration-300"></div>
                        <button type="submit" class="w-full font-heading font-medium text-base text-white overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                            <div class="relative py-4 px-9 bg-gradient-blue overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                                <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 transform -translate-y-full group-hover:-translate-y-0 h-full w-full bg-blue-900 transition ease-in-out duration-500"></div>
                                <p class="relative z-10">Terminer le test</p>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="{{asset('assets/js/practicalTest.js')}}"></script>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: For anything complex with forms I would strongly recommend using a custom FormType. Having multiple forms only nested in html is a recipe for desaster. Have you tried https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html ? there's also something like event listeners in symfony form, with which you can extend the form depending on the data being preset/submitted for that form.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The problem I have is this. My form represents a quiz and has about 50 fields. I was afraid to use Form Collection because of performance problems if the complete collection is over 200 fields long.

Comment: Have you actually encountered performance problems? And if you have, maybe your approach is suboptimal. If I had 200 fields, I probably wouldn't even *want* them in just one form, but rather have a "quiz session", show one "page" at a time, and update stuff in the session. some js on top could make it smooth for the user. or is it a requirement to keep everything in one form to produce one single big submit?

Comment: also, to get rid of the error message, you probably have to allow extra fields on the form. which is just a config parameter on the form ... https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields

Comment: Could you share a screenshot to see clearly what you want to do?

Comment: For the moment, I haven't tested using a form with 200 fields, but I've decided that in terms of performance, it's not a good idea. I therefore decided to use one form per student.

I'd like to allow one examiner to assess four students at the same time. The way I see it, each student is assigned a form (each form contains 50 fields).

Here's a screenshot (the tabs are missing here- each tab contains a table with a form) : https://imgur.com/a/RWxUTua